# Calculate correlations between data.frame columns and assign output to list

Tags: r

Given this data.frame:

```
 Age <- c(23, 41, 32, 58, 26)
 e <- c(23, 41, 32, 58, 26)
 Ag <- c(23, 41, 32, 58, 26)
 df <- data.frame(Ag,e, Age)
```

I would like to use cor to compute the correlation between Ag and all other columns in the data.frame (they are many not only two). Then return the results in a list with names of columns as

```
>lst
$e
[1] 1

$Age
[1] 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `base R`

```
as.list(cor(df)[1,-1])
```

-output

```
$e
[1] 1

$Age
[1] 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr`.

`summarise` allows us to select which columns to apply a custom function to - in this case, all columns other than `Ag`, with the custom function performing the correlation between Ag and the selected ones.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% summarise(across(-Ag, function(x) cor(x, Ag))) %>% as.list
```

```
$e
[1] 1

$Age
[1] 1
```